# 5 queens on a 8x8 chess board

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to find the number of ways possible to set 5 queens on a chess board without them being able to attack each other. I have succeeded to find the first set. The problem is how would I be able to find the next set of positions for 5 queens. The procedure in my program is like this:

- Generate a vector of disallowed positions based on the current queens on the board
- Loop through all the positions on the board
- Check if the current position is one of the disallowed positions on the board
- If it is not, return the position, add it to the vector of queens on the board and begin the process again

Continue until there is no more position available i.e. all the remaining positions are disallowed

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
const int BSIZE = 8;
char chessBoard[BSIZE][BSIZE];

struct qPos
{
    qPos() : h(0), v(0), found(true) {}
    int h; //horizontal pos
    int v; //vertical pos
    bool found; //if position is available
};

qPos findNextQPos(vector<qPos> Qs);
void fillBoard(vector<qPos> Qs);
void print();
vector<qPos> generateDisallowed(vector<qPos> Qs);
bool isDisallowed(qPos nextPos, vector<qPos> disallowedPos);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    vector<qPos> QsOnBoard; //Position of all the queens on board
    qPos nextQ; //next possible position
    while (nextQ.found)
    {
        nextQ = findNextQPos(QsOnBoard);
        if (nextQ.found)
        {
            QsOnBoard.push_back(nextQ); //If the nextQ is available i.e. not disallowed, add it to the queens vector
        }
    }
    fillBoard(QsOnBoard); //Fill the board with queens positions
    print(); // print the board
    return 0;
}

qPos findNextQPos(vector<qPos> Qs) {
    // Generate disallowed positions based on all the queens on board
    vector <qPos> disallowedPos = generateDisallowed(Qs);
    qPos nextQ;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < BSIZE; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < BSIZE; j++)
        {
            nextQ.h = i;
            nextQ.v = j;
            if (!isDisallowed(nextQ, disallowedPos)) { //Check if next possible position is a disallowed position
                //cout << "Next available:\n" << nextQ.h << ", " << nextQ.v << endl;
                return nextQ; // if it is avaible return the position, break the loop
            }
        }
    }
    nextQ.found = false; // No available position is found to return, found is set to false, return the position
    return nextQ;
}
```

Rest of the source code where I have the other functions such as generate disallowed and isDisallowed and etc is on [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/MVnT90r8). I thought it would not be really related to the question and the code here should not be too long.

The result of the first set looks like this: 
[image]
So how should I continue in order to be able to find all solution sets? This is where I get stuck.

Comment: Are you required to use code, or would a combinatorial solution suffice?

Comment: @abiessu I'd prefer to use code. With the combinational solution I wouldn't have even needed to come this far, right? Could calculate based on the size of the board and number of queens, I suppose.

Comment: Why do I get down vote on this question? Could anybody explain it to me?

Comment: Not sure about the down vote, you seem to have done some work on your own to attempt a solution and you seem to have tried to understand the problem space yourself.  I suggest the combinatorial route since going through every solution will almost certainly produce many duplicate queen formations, including rotations and flips and translations through the chessboard space.

Comment: @abiessu Yeah I know with the rotations and flips there would be a bunch of solutions, but I actually am looking for unique solutions. But just out of curiosity, would you tell me the combinatorial solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, combine these two loops into one:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < BSIZE; i++)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < BSIZE; j++)
    {
```

Instead:

```
for (size_t n = 0; n < (BSIZE * BSIZE); ++n)
{
    size_t i = n % BSIZE;
    size_t j = n / BSIZE;
```

Now your function can easily take a starting `n`. To find the "next" solution, simply remove the last queen (noting its position) and call `FindNextQPos`, telling it to start at the position one past that queen. If that queen is already at the last position, go back and remove another queen.

If you find no solution, do the same thing as if you do find a solution. Remove the last queen and call `FindNextQPos`, again starting one past the position of the queen you removed.

When you have no queens to remove, you are done.

You can do this with a single "continue" function. You can call this function whether you found a solution or found no solution. Its logic is:

1. Find the last queen. If there's no last queen, stop. We are done.
2. Note its position. Remove it.
3. Call `FindNextQPos` starting at the position one past the position we noted. If we placed a queen, keep trying to place more queens starting at position zero until we find a solution or can't place a queen.
4. If we found a solution, output it.
5. Go to step 1.

Comment: It sounds that it would work! It's a bit hard for me to understand it by just reading, but I try it out. So basically what we're doing is moving the last queen always forward until we hit the end. Then move another queen, right? What happens to the queen that went to the end?

Comment: When a queen hits the end, you remove it. Then you repeat, again removing the last queen and trying to advance it. (To understand the algorithm, it may be worth just mentally considering the case where you're just trying to place five pieces *anywhere* on the board. Then you just need to count, which is exactly what this algorithm does. When you count, how do you get from 19 to 20? There is no next digit after 9, so you remove the last digit, increment the first digit, and then try to place a new last digit starting from zero.)

Comment: I am sorry if I sound like an idiot here, but if I remove the queen on the board, there would be 4 queens left and it's not 5 anymore. That opens up a lot of new ways of setting them.

Comment: @Erfan I'm not sure I follow you. You have to start by placing one queen on an empty board. Then you have to place a second queen on a board with one queen already on it. (It may help you to work through a simple example, say outputting every three-digit number. First you place the first digit, then the second, then the third, then you output a solution. Then you remove the third digit and try to place a larger one in its place. And so on.)